# MySQL query returning doubles

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For some reason when I run this query it returns the same data twice (doubles). The data is only in the database once. Why is it returning doubles? I can't figure it out.

Note: I'm new to these kind of queries, so any guidance is much appreciated.

```
SELECT 
             `conversations_messages`.`message_date`,
             `conversations_messages`.`message_date` > `conversations_members`.`conversation_last_view` AS `message_unread`,
             `conversations_messages`.`message_text`,
             `users`.`username`
      FROM   `conversations_messages`
      INNER JOIN `users` ON `conversations_messages`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`
      INNER JOIN `conversations_members` ON `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_members`.`conversation_id`
      WHERE `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}
      ORDER BY `conversations_messages`.`message_date` DESC
```

.....
Here is the function in it's entirety.

```
function fetch_conversation_messages ($conversation_id) {
$conversation_id=(int)$conversation_id;
$sql="SELECT 
             `conversations_messages`.`message_date`,
             `conversations_messages`.`message_date` > `conversations_members`.`conversation_last_view` AS `message_unread`,
             `conversations_messages`.`message_text`,
             `users`.`username`
      FROM   `conversations_messages`
      INNER JOIN `users` ON `conversations_messages`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`
      INNER JOIN `conversations_members` ON `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_members`.`conversation_id`
      WHERE `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id` = {$conversation_id}
      ORDER BY `conversations_messages`.`message_date` DESC";

     $result = mysqli_query($sql);
     $messages = array();

     while (($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false){
       $messages[] = array(
            'date'      => $row['message_date'],
            'unread'    => $row['message_unread'],
            'text'      => $row['message_text'],
            'username'  => $row['username'],
       );
}
     return $messages;
```

}

Comment: please show your php as well

Comment: Thanks, michi. I have included the entire function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is creating a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).  I assume there are two conversation members for each message, and the join is matching both of them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Bill! I'm pretty new to these big queries (days new). Any idea how I fix the problem? I can't really pick it apart.

Comment: That is, what do I need to change exactly?

Comment: I solved the problem. I forgot to include the line: " AND `conversations_members`.`user_id`={$_SESSION['user_id']}" ...I have another problem now where the logged in user's reply repeats a bunch of times. - I'm sure it's just a typo somewhere, though.

Comment: @BernieAllen make sure you mark the question as "solved" by clicking on the tick icon